# Is it possible to declare strong parameters in a variable to share among controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have the following models:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_one :application
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Correspondingly, I have the following code in my controllers:

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def application_params
    params.require(:application).permit(
      ...
      profile_attributes: [:title, :name]
    )
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      ...
      profile_attributes: [:title, :name]
    )
  end
end

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:title, :name)
  end
end
```

As you can see the same permitted attributes (:title, :name) are defined in three places.

Is there any way to avoid this? For example would it be possible to define the profile parameters in a variable and use that?

Example (doesn't work):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  permitted_profile_attributes = [:title, :name]
  ...
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      ...
      profile_attributes: permitted_profile_attributes
    )
  end
end
```

Or do I have to define the permitted attributes separately in each controller and live with the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def permitted_profile_attributes
    [:title, :name]
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      ...
      profile_attributes: permitted_profile_attributes
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.